# how to user insert_rows_from_dataframe?? Python to Bigquery

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Example My DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4,5,4], 'b': ['121233', '45a56', '0000'], 'c':['sas53d1', '1asdf23', '2asdf456']})
```

my Bigquery Table Path

```
table = 'tutorial.b'
```

So i make a Table with

```
client.load_table_from_dataframe(df,table)
```

Then i make a bigquery table in tutorial.b
So i want to insert another dataframe

```
df1 = df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'c':['casd33', 'dfsf12', 'lsdfkj3']})
```

so user insert_rows_from_dataframe

```
client.insert_rows_from_dataframe(table = table_path, dataframe = df1)
client.insert_rows_from_dataframe(df1, table_path)
```

i try this two code but always same error

```
The table argument should be a table ID string, Table, or TableReference
```

how to insert my dataframe to already exist table?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements and what you mean by `insert my dataframe to already exist table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for the 2 Dataframe, use the same method : [load_table_from_dataframe](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe#code-sample) but with different options :

- If you want to load the dataframe to table and create the table :

```py
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("title", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
            bigquery.SchemaField("wikidata_id", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        ],
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    )

    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.
    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
```

- If you want to load the dataframe to an existing table without recreate it :

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("title", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
            bigquery.SchemaField("wikidata_id", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        ],
        create_disposition="CREATE_NEVER",
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
    )

    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.
    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
```

I used a fake schema in my examples, but it's not mandatory in your case.

The `job_config` allows to indicate the options for the ingestion.